# Java Freemaker spaces in number

Tags: java, freemarker

Hello i have such template:

```
......
<body onload='setInterval(function(){refresh()}, ${refreshPeriod} ); setClientTime();'>
<p>UserId: ${userId}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

when i generate my template and put userId like `4195578878989842599` it display like `4 195 578 878 989 842 599`, is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`c`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_c).

> This built-in converts a number to string for a "computer language" as opposed to for human audience.

```
${userId?c}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be set globally using the FreeMarker configuration. See [manual entry](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config.html) under Settings - setNumberFormat